# Android: show a dialog after 5 seconds

Tags: android, timer, fragment, android-alertdialog

I would like to show an alert dialog, after 5 seconds I am on a certain fragment.

Which is the safest way to do that?
avoiding for example to show the dialog in case the fragment is in the process of being paused or destroyed

any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Use this code inside your Fragment `onCreateView()` method:

```
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(this!=null && !isFinishing()){
                        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this,
                                "Please Wait... ", "Loading... ", false, true);
                        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    }
                }
            }, 5000);
```

This will show a `ProgressDialog` within 5 seconds. Once the 5 seconds pass, it checks if the `Activity` is not null or if it is not in the process of finishing. In case it is not, your `ProgressDialog` shows, and you can cancel it just by hitting back button.

Answer (score 0):

```
     final ProgressDialog dialog= ProgressDialog.show(this,"Doing something", "Please wait....",true);  
     new Thread(new Runnable() {  
         @Override  
         public void run() {  
             try {  
             Thread.sleep(5000);  
                 dialog.dismiss();  
             }  
             catch(InterruptedException ex){  
                 ex.printStackTrace();  
             }  
         }  
     }).start();
```

This solution worked for me. It dismisses dialog automatically.